# JSON: Extract and print both key and value pair for value matching pattern

Tags: json, jq

JSON:

```
"{
  "a": "https://is2-ssl.com/",
  "b": "https://a5.-ssl.com/",
  "type": "response",
  "c": [
    {
      "Number": 1,
      "Reportname": "XXX",
      "size": "2.5",
      "Variants": [
        "YYY"
      ]
    }
  ],
"Meta": "ABC"
}
```

Required Output:

```
XXX,a,https://is2-ssl.com/
XXX,b,https://a5.-ssl.com/
```

I want to print those key value pairs in which the value contains "http"(url) and merge the key and value with delimiter "," and add ReportName to them

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. We're not really a free code-writing service. So, seeing you know that you should be using `jq`, please tell us where you're stuck – much easier to help you if you share your approach with us!

Comment: i am completely new to json and jq. I tried using select, contains, with_entries but not able to print both key and value pair if value matche pattern

Comment: Wow, well that's already pretty involved? Mind sharing (by editing your question) one of these approaches? I'm not too much of a jq-magician either, but I think with your help it's easy for the community to piece something together, even on a (traditionally slightly slow) Sunday evening.

Comment: `c` appears to be an array. What should happen if there are several entries in that array?  Is the initial double quote (which is unmatched) a typo? Are you showing the actual keys in the document? If not, it would be helpful if you could do that. It is unusual for a JSON structure to be this unorganised, so if you have a real document to share, that would be preferred. Extracting data _by value_ (rather than by key) is also a bit unusual.

Comment: Can someone provide some site or book to master jq and json parsing. i read jq manual but still i cant handle complex parsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the initial `"` in the JSON document is a typo, that you want the `.ReportName` key's value from the *first* entry in the `c` array, and that you want the output as CSV:

```bash
$ jq -r '.c[0].Reportname as $n | map_values(select(type == "string" and startswith("http"))) | to_entries[] | [$n, .key, .value] | @csv' file
"XXX","a","https://is2-ssl.com/"
"XXX","b","https://a5.-ssl.com/"
```

The `jq` expression:

```
.c[0].Reportname as $n |
map_values(select(type == "string" and startswith("http"))) |
to_entries[] | [$n, .key, .value] | @csv
```

This first picks out the `.Reportname` value and assigns it to the internal `jq` variable `$n`. It then rewrites the original object by discarding any key not associated with a string starting with the substring `http`.

The example document is, after `map_values()` reduced to

```json
{
  "a": "https://is2-ssl.com/",
  "b": "https://a5.-ssl.com/"
}
```

This is then converted with `to_entries` into the equivalent of

```json
[
   { "key": "a", "value": "https://is2-ssl.com/" },
   { "key": "b", "value": "https://a5.-ssl.com/" }
]
```

... to get access to the keys themselves.

This array is expanded into a set of objects with `[]` and the saved value in `$n` together with the `.key` and `.value` part of each object in the set is used to create an array that is converted by `@csv` to quoted CSV output.

---

Another `jq` expression with the same output, but that does `to_entries` a bit earlier and then does `map()` on the created array rather than on the values of an object as we do with `map_values()` above.

```
.c[0].Reportname as $n | 
to_entries | 
map(
   select(.value | type == "string" and startswith("http")) |
   [$n, .key, .value] | @csv
)[]
```